# How to replace a certain value across a list of dataframe columns with random values efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (a very large one) that looks as follows:

| id | class_number | a_1 | a_2 | a_3 | a_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 |

For the sake of completeness, here is a screenshot containing a larger cutout of this dataframe:

[image]

How can we replace all ones (all values `1`) within the columns `a_1` to `a_1000` each with a random value other than `0`, `1` and `2`?

What I tried so far works but seems not to be elegant:

```
cols = ["a_" + str(i) for i in range(1, 1000+1)]

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: random.choice(range(3, 20)) if x == 1 else x)
df.head()
```

I would be greatful for any hint to implement this in a more staright-forward manner.
Note `df[cols].apply(...)` does not work, since it yields an error *"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."*

Comment: First include data as text and NOT as images.

Comment: Sorry - good point. Will fix it immediatly.

Comment: `df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.replace({1:random.choice(range(3, 20))}))`?

Comment: `df[cols].apply(lambda x: np.where(x==1, random.choice(range(3,20)), x))`

Comment: Thank you for these hints - are these working inplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
cols = df.filter(like='a_').columns

df[cols] = df.mask(df[cols].eq(1),
                   np.random.randint(3,1000,(df.shape[0], len(cols))))
```

reproducible example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,10)),
                  columns=[f'a_{i+1}' for i in range(10)])
```

output:

```
   a_1  a_2  a_3  a_4  a_5  a_6  a_7  a_8  a_9  a_10
0    5    0    3    3    7    9    3    5    2     4
1    7    6    8    8  957    6    7    7    8   380
2    5    9    8    9    4    3    0    3    5     0
3    2    3    8  785    3    3    3    7    0    89
4    9    9    0    4    7    3    2    7    2     0
5    0    4    5    5    6    8    4  592    4     9
6    8  773  518    7    9    9    3    6    7     2
7    0    3    5    9    4    4    6    4    4     3
8    4    4    8    4    3    7    5    5    0   846
9    5    9    3    0    5    0   28    2    4     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, which is very helpful. There seems to be a minor issue. He yields `ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray` at the line `df = `.  But it is a minor issue that is easy to fix.

Comment: weird, it should have the same shape because of `(df.shape[0], len(cols))`…

Comment: I committed the notebook [here to GitHub](https://github.com/Sultanow/number_fields/blob/main/python/notebooks_kaggle/zeta-count-coeff-values.ipynb) showing the error. The dataset is publicly available too [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/eldarsultanow/real-quad-fields-1-2).

Comment: I checked the shapes - they looks to be equal: `print(df.shape)` and `print(df.mask(df[cols].eq(1)).shape)` both yield `(360591, 1006)`.

Comment: Yes - that is a very good starting point for me to proceed. Your answer is great and efficient. Thank you again. The last minor issue I will figure out myself. The reason might be that I have a column more, namely `class_number` which is out of consideration.